# Matlab) Label the random points in plotted graph (voronoi)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

```
clc
clear all

xn = rand(20,1) * 200;  
yn = rand(20,1) * 100;  
Start = [0 0];  
End = [200 100];
[vx, vy] = voronoi(xn, yn); 
idx = ((vx(1,:)< Start(1,1)) | vx(2,:)< Start(1,1) | vx(1,:)> End(1,1) | vx(2,:)> End(1,1) | (vy(1,:)< Start(1,2)) | vy(2,:)< Start(1,2) | vy(1,:)> End(1,2) | vy(2,:)> End(1,2));
newx = vx;
newx(:,idx)=[];
newy = vy;
newy(:,idx)=[];

figure(1);
plot(xn, yn, 'b.', 'markersize', 10);
hold on;
xlabel('X direction(m)');
ylabel('Y direction(m)');
axis([0 200 0 100])


figure(2);
plot(xn,yn,'b.','markersize', 10);
hold on;
plot(vx ,vy, 'g-');
xlabel('X direction(m)');
ylabel('Y direction(m)');
axis([0 200 0 100])


figure(3);
plot(newx, newy, 'b.', 'markersize', 10);
hold on;
plot(newx, newy, 'g-');
xlabel('X direction(m)');check
ylabel('Y direction(m)');
title('Problem Space with vertices');
axis([0 200 0 100])
```

I have this code over here for voronoi diagram. I need to spread 20 points randomly. Afterwards I need to remove unwanted vertices. But how do I get to label the random points? As shown in the picture. I have everything but the labelled points.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLBWw.png)

Comment: How about using `text(..)`? Something like `text(newx(1:2), newy(1:2), {'A', 'B'})`